# Angular doesn't update the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have worked with angular for long time without facing many problems until now. I have a controller which calls a function when a ng-change event occurs. I have a set of different reports that are generated depending on some select filters defined in the main controller called Principal (PrincipalController).

Most of the controllers work fine and generate what they suppose, however with the last one (AnalisisEvaluacionController) I am struggling.

Its view is loaded correctly in the beginning. I print the name in the view but when I called the method from a ng-change event the name does not change. I also have a ng-repeat over $scope.notas which does not work. Actually that is the real issue. I have read about it and I have tried with 
$scope.$apply() and $scope.$digest() but the error

```
angular.js:14800 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress is thrown
```

I have created a snippet with the code https://bitbucket.org/snippets/jorguerra/Ee6G6y

I basically have a ng-repeat over evaluacion.notas which is reloaded when the function generarInforme is call, which call a factory that brings a JSON back which is assigned to $scope.evaluacion in the controller. The problem is that I can iterate or show the data I need to display

Comment: Have you tried `$timeout(function() {$scope.$apply()}, 0)` ?

Comment: why do you need to call `$scope.$apply();` I guess your code execution is already in angular context

Comment: @Jorge can you put your code on plunkr >

Comment: it's hard to diagnose what is going on here without seeing your HTML, but what you are describing can occur because `ng-repeat` creates a separate child scope.  it's likely that this is causing your controller to not be updating these values properly.  One cardinal rule of angularjs is **always have a dot in HTML bindings** to avoid this problem.  The Controller As syntax became popular because it automatically enforces this, and reduces your dependence on `$scope` in the process.

Comment: `$scope.$apply()` should only be used as a last resort, when you know you are updating a value without angular's knowledge (like in a jquery script).  Usually, if you find yourself trying to use `$scope.$apply()` you have something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call $scope.$apply (or $digest) in ng-change handler, as it's handler is already wrapped in $scope.$apply block. If you, however need to call $scope.$apply (or $digest) in some situations (e.g. your ng-change handler does some asynchronous operation after which you need to sync the view model), you can prevent the error this way:

```
(scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase) ? fn() : scope.$apply(fn);
```

You can also wrap your `fn` in `$timeout` block

```
$timeout(fn)
```

which safely applies $scope.$apply.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by creating a function init inside of AnalisisEvaluacionController which calls the method generarInforme and changing set all the required variables.